# PHP comparing two dates for expire date

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

Hi i'm trying to make something that compares dates from my database to check if my license is expired.

My dates are stored in this format: `18/05/2019` (d/m/Y)

in my code i create a variable for today's date:

```
$TodayDate = Date('d/m/Y');
```

then i get the row that contains the date in my database like so:

```
$DBLicenseExpireDate  = $row["LicenseExpireDate"];
```

and finally  i try to see if the date is expired:

```
 if ($TodayDate < $DBLicenseExpireDate) {
           }
```

i've also tried:

```
 if ($TodayDate < strtotime($DBLicenseExpireDate)) {
           }
```

in almost all cases i tried it said it was expired while it was not.

I get some weird results. Example:
If today's date is : 05/18/2019 and the expire date is: 06/06/2019 
and i try this if statement:

```
if($todayDate < $expireDate)
{
  echo 'not expired';
}
else
{
echo 'expired';
}
```

it still results as expired. 
seen million questions about checking expire dates, tried them all. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: If you don't want to code this yourself, use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use `strtotime()` for date math. Use `DateTime() which is much better suited for working with dates.
2. Your date format is not compatible with `strtotime()`. When using m/d/Y format is is assumed that you are using US date format and dates like `18/05/2019` is evaluated as "the fifth day of the 18th month of 2019". Obviously that is not what you mean and you will get [1970-01-01](https://3v4l.org/VmuLr) as a result.

Use [`DateTime::CreateFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to get the date you want and then do your comparison:

```
// Parse the european date format
$date1 = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('%d/%m/%Y', '18/05/2019');
// Get today ("now")
$date2 = new DateTime(); 
// DateTime objects are comparable so you can compare these two variables directly
if ($date2 < $date1) {
    // today is before the 18th of May
}
else {
    // today is after the 18th of May
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't beat me to it. You're a quick gun and I am slow when on my chromebook (but I love it anyway).

Comment: And a good answer it is :)

Comment: Thanks John - always appreciate the kudos from someone with your level of experience on the site.

Comment: Thanks a lot! ```$expdate = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('d/m/Y', $DBLicenseExpireDate); ``` fixed it for me!

Answer (score -1):

```
$TodayDate = Date('d/m/Y');
echo '<br/>'.$TodayDate;

//$DBLicenseExpireDate  = $row["LicenseExpireDate"];
//Suppose $DBLicenseExpireDate is 17/05/2019
$DBLicenseExpireDate = '17/05/2019';
echo '<br/>'.$DBLicenseExpireDate;

$TodayDateDateTimeStamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('!d/m/Y', $TodayDate)->getTimestamp();
$DBLicenseExpireDateDateTimeStamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('!d/m/Y', $DBLicenseExpireDate)->getTimestamp();

echo '<br/>'.$TodayDateDateTimeStamp;
echo '<br/>'.$DBLicenseExpireDateDateTimeStamp;

if($TodayDateDateTimeStamp > $DBLicenseExpireDateDateTimeStamp)
    echo "<br/>License Expired";
else
    echo "<br/>Not Expired";
```

Reference https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I had to downvote you because your answer is the same as mine but you don't bother to explain *why* it solves their problem. I also don't know why you linked to `strtotime()` when it isn't part of your answer. And PHP does not have a  built in `Date()` class.

Comment: He's calling the date() function but using an uppercase D which works the same.

Comment: @JohnConde have you run my code ? Run this and if you are getting any error let me know. Downvote is okay. As you have posted it just few min ago.. doen't mean i have copied your code.. Thanks